# Chart does not load in first run

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a chart based on data of a GridView, so if a user select a row in my grid view I execute the chart create as:

```
     private void dgvUserActivity_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                var dg = (DataGridView)sender;
                if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;
                var selectedrowindex = dg.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                var selectedRow = dg.Rows[selectedrowindex];
    
                var selectedUserName = selectedRow.Cells["UserName"].Value.ToString();
    
                UserActivityAuditModel = UserActivityModel.UserActivityAuditList.Where(x => x.UserName == selectedUserName).ToList();
    
                ClearChartPoints();
                userChart.Titles.Clear();
                LoadChart(UserActivityAuditModel);
            }
```

Then I load chart as:

```
 private void LoadChart(IList<UserActivityAuditViewModel> model)
        {
            //Filter info

            var selectedTime = new List<TimeSpan>();
            if (rdoLogOn.Checked)
            {
               selectedTime = model.Select(x => x.AverageLogOn).ToList();
            }
            else if (rdoLogOff.Checked)
            {
                selectedTime = model.Select(x => x.AverageLogOff).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                selectedTime = model.Select(x => x.AverageTotalHours).ToList();
            }


            Axis XA = userChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            Axis YA = userChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
            Series S1 = userChart.Series[0];
            S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

            //Add or change Title
            var title = new Title();
            title.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
            title.Text = Helpers.FirstCharToUpper(model.Select(x => x.UserName).FirstOrDefault());
            userChart.Titles.Add(title);

            var dates = model.Select(x => x.ActivityDate).ToList();

            var currentRegister = 0;
            foreach (DateTime d in dates)
            {
                var yValue = selectedTime[currentRegister].ToString();
                S1.Points.AddXY(d, yValue);
                currentRegister++;
            }

            var dt = DateTime.Now;
            S1.LegendText = "Year " + dt.Year;

            // move to the bottom center:
            userChart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
            userChart.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;


            if (!rdoTotalHours.Checked)
            {
                S1.YValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
                XA.LabelStyle.Format = "mm:ss";
            }
            else
            {
              

            }

            S1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
            XA.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            XA.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM";

            XA.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
            XA.Interval = 1;


            YA.IsInterlaced = true;
            //YA.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            YA.InterlacedColor = Color.FromArgb(31, Color.LightSeaGreen);
        }
```

For some reason in my first clic of DataGridView it executes the chart create,I debug it and the problem is in this `foreach clause` :

```
  foreach (DateTime d in dates)
                {
                    var yValue = selectedTime[currentRegister].ToString();
                    S1.Points.AddXY(d, yValue);
                    currentRegister++;
                }
```

The value is there, after `S1.Points.AddXY(d, yValue);` is executed, I debug Points Y value is always 0 but the yValue I set has the correct number!. This is really weird.

Pictures:

[image: Picture1]

As you can see value is there, but when I press F10 to continue debugging:

[image]

It added as 0 instead my value

Note: As I say before, this is only first time load, if I clic again in any row, it load correctly, someone have an idea of what is happening there? Regards

**----EDIT----**

I get the `yValue` from my global model:

```
public IList<UserActivityAuditViewModel> UserActivityAuditModel { get; set; } = new List<UserActivityAuditViewModel>();
```

Then I assign it depending of some radio buttons on the beginning of chart method:

```
    var selectedTime = new List<TimeSpan>();
    if (rdoLogOn.Checked)
    {
       selectedTime = model.Select(x => x.AverageLogOn).ToList();
    }
    else if (rdoLogOff.Checked)
    {
        selectedTime = model.Select(x => x.AverageLogOff).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        selectedTime = model.Select(x => x.AverageTotalHours).ToList();
    }
```

and I use that `TimeSpan` list into `yValue`

I create a simple test, instead load my `Y` value with `TimeSpan` I create an int list as:

```
var testList = new List<int>();
            testList.Add(1);
            testList.Add(2);
            testList.Add(3);
            testList.Add(4);
            testList.Add(5);
            testList.Add(6);
            testList.Add(7);
            testList.Add(8);
            testList.Add(9);
            testList.Add(10);
            testList.Add(11);
            testList.Add(12);
            testList.Add(13);
```

Then I use in `foreach` as

```
  foreach (DateTime d in dates)
        {
            var yValue = testList[currentRegister].ToString();
            S1.Points.AddXY(d, yValue);
            currentRegister++;
        }
```

And now chart load in first load, but I can not understand why is not working with TimeSpan in first load, can someone have an idea of what is happening and a solution for this?

Comment: Weird, can you clean solution, then close VS, then manually delete your obj, bin folders plus the suo file and then can you reproduce it? **Also where is yValue declared, what is its datatype? A Time, hmm I don't think that will work if the X-Axis ticks are dates**

Comment: That value is declare at the top of method, I have a global model, then I get the list of that model as TimeSpan and I use it in foreach, I will try that @JeremyThompson

Comment: Just to test the theory, try represent the time as a number, eg 08.54  `yValue.ToString().Substring(0,4).Replace(":",".");`

Comment: OMG! It Works.. why??, well it set a value to Y but is not my value it  always set 12:00, I think that happens becuase it's not more an TimeSpan @JeremyThompson

Comment: It set it as 8.54 for example, but when it try to change format to Time I think that changes to 12 at the end of the day, so it's there a workaround to set AddXY with timespan at the first load? @JeremyThompson

Comment: Can you share the declaration of `yValue`?

Comment: I update my question with the declaration of `yValue` @JeremyThompson

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue

Charts does not support `TimeSpan`, so for some reason at the first render of chart it conflicts with `Chart` data. So the simplest solution I found is to convert `TimeSpan` to DateTime, at the end of the day we use `YValueType` as `Time` so it will take the `time` of the `DateTime` and display instead Date:

```
foreach (DateTime d in dates)
        {
            var datetime = new DateTime(0).AddSeconds(selectedTime[currentRegister].TotalSeconds);
            S1.Points.AddXY(d, datetime);
            currentRegister++;
        }
```